# VB.Net How can I create a new file with parentheses in filename

Tags: vb.net, filenames

I'm controlling a camera from my windows app and save the images under auto-generated filenames (like "M32-L1_420s_1x1_-20C.fit"). Usually I would take images with different filters. The number behind the filter name represents the number of the recording series (like L1, R1, G1, B1, L2, R2, ...). Now it happens that sometimes I need to run two images in a series with the same filter. For that case, I check if the file does exist already and (want to) add "(2)" to the number of the second instance of the file. An example would be:

```
filename = object & "-" & filtername & repeat & "(2)_" & exposuretime & ... & ".fit"
```

Windows throws an error and will refuse to create and write to that file. I didn't really expect this, because windows is doing this very thing when you copy an existing file and you decide to "copy and keep the original". I tried to replace the "(2)" with "%282%29" which creates a file with ...%282%29... in the filename!

Comment: Works for me.  Something else must be going on.  Could you post the shortest full sample of working code that reproduces the error (an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) along with the full error message that you're receiving?

Comment: @Steven: Thanks for looking into this. I'm not on my own computer right now. Will provide more code asap.

Comment: FYI, to test it, I just stuck a single line in a console app, ran it, and it worked no problem (on Windows 7, that is): `System.IO.File.WriteAllText("M32-L1_420s_1x1_-20C.fit", "blah")`

Comment: @Steven: Thanks. First the error message: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'WriteToFile: couldn't create file C:\PlateSolving\PatsAstroUtility\Data\M32_L1(2)_4s_1x1_-20C.fit'. Your example should be "M32-L1(2)_420s_1x1_-20C.fit". It's the parentheses that cause the trouble. If that works for you, then I guess it's the FITS.dll (which provides the WriteToFile method). Not a lot I can do then, I'm afraid... Thanks again!

Comment: Ha!  Whoops.  Yeah, my original test was with a file name that had parentheses.  Anyway, `System.IO.File.WriteAllText("M32-L1(2)_420s_1x1_-20C.fit", "blah")` does work for me, as it should for you, if you try it.  So, it sounds like it's a problem with that `FITS.dll`, whatever that is.  I've never heard of it.

Comment: @Steven: .fit is an image format used in astrophotography. FITS.dll lets you read and write it (among others). So it's going to be a "-2" then instead of "(2)". Thanks again!